# How to flatten a Flowable<ListenableFuture<List<T>>> to Flowable<T> asynchronously?

Tags: rx-java

I'm using RxJava 2.0.0-RC4.

In my application I receive a `Flowable<ListenableFuture<List<Integer>>`. (`ListenableFuture` comes from Guava.)

How can I flatten this flowable into a `Flowable<Integer>`?

I tried this:

```
Flowable<ListenableFuture<List<Integer>>> futures = ...
Flowable<Integer> ints = futures.flatMap(future -> Flowable.fromIterable(future.get()));
```

But that involves a blocking call (`Future.get()`). Ideally I would like to create the flowable in a fully non-blocking way, so that it would emit items as soon as the underlying futures would complete (I don't have the requirement to preserve ordering of elements in the resulting flowable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    ListenableFuture<List<Integer>> listListenableFuture = Futures.immediateFuture(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    Flowable<List<Integer>> futures = Flowable.fromCallable(() -> listListenableFuture.get());

    Flowable<Integer> integerFlowable = futures
            .flatMap(integers -> Flowable.fromIterable(integers));

    TestSubscriber<Integer> test = integerFlowable.test();

    test.assertValues(1, 2, 3);
}
```

If you introduce subscribeOn/ observeOn, the test will fail. I would recommand wrapping the ListenableFuture by hooking in the lifecycle events.

Wrapping would look something like this:

```
    @Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    ListenableFuture<List<Integer>> listListenableFuture = Futures.immediateFuture(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));

    Flowable<List<Integer>> listFlowable = Flowable.create(e -> {
        if (e.isCancelled()) {
            return;
        }

        try {
            FutureCallback<List<Integer>> futureCallback = new FutureCallback<List<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<Integer> result) {
                    if (!e.isCancelled()) {
                        printCurrentThread("inOnSuccess");

                        e.onNext(result);
                        e.onComplete();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                    if (!e.isCancelled()) {
                        e.onError(t);
                    }
                }
            };

            Futures.addCallback(listListenableFuture, futureCallback);

            e.setDisposable(Disposables.fromFuture(listListenableFuture, true));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            e.onError(ex);
        }

    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

    Flowable<Integer> integerFlowable = listFlowable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .doOnNext(integers -> printCurrentThread("afterObserveOn"))
            .flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable);

    TestSubscriber<Integer> test = integerFlowable.test();

    Thread.sleep(200);

    test.assertResult(1, 2, 3);
}

private void printCurrentThread(String additional) {
    System.out.println(additional + "_" + Thread.currentThread());
}
```

Comment: Your second solution works and is exactly the kind of callback style that I was looking for, thank you very much! For the record, I had to replace BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER with FlowableEmitter.BackpressureMode.BUFFER.

Comment: I added some more isCancelled tests.